# What to do with Pickled Figs

Tags: culinary-uses, fruit

I have a jar of pickled figs bought for me as a present, and would like to make good use of them. Any ideas??

Comment: I love figs and pickled things, but I can't quite place this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the two most likely things to do with this are to serve it as an accompaniment to a cheese plate (preferably with a triple cream / brie type cheese or an intense blue cheese), or in a dish with a gamey meat.

Comment: yes, this sounds like it is the best use - now to find a good brie. I might melt try melting it a little on toast.

Answer (score 0):

I would stuff one inside a quail before cooking.  You should get a really nice gamey-figgy gravy out of it.

Answer (score 0):

I would just eat them as a side with dinner. YUM!  Our family can't have Thanksgiving dinner without pickled figs on the table.

Answer (score -1):

Iread that they can be used in a casserole. I have some Spanish ones preserved in vinegar.They did not go down well as an apero / cheese accompaniment so I'm stuck with them. Would like some ideas.